# Many facebook like-buttons - same page

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-like

I have a very interesting question - I see there are some way to have many like buttons
on the same page by making manually link for every button.

Thing is that I´m programming a page with a menu for restaurant and the owner wants
each meal on the menu to have a "like-button" - each meal is in a box that arrange over the page so he can have 2 meals or 100 meals on that same page.

The info in the menu comes from a mysql table like this SELECT FROM menu ORDER BY id DESC (no limit) - so it multiplies all over the page so making a special url for each like-button
is not an option

Is this do-able?

Answer (score 0):

Its good to use Ajax, in this case.